# Efficient way to check if sum is possible from a given set of numbers

Tags: c++, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

Given a set of unique positive integers (size ranging upto `32`), it is required to determine whether a required sum is possible or not.

A brute force approach is:

```
bool isPossible(long long int n, int s)
{
    if(n<0)
        return false;
    if(n == 0)
        return true;
    for(int i=s;i<32;++i)
        if(isPossible(n-allNumbers[i], i+1))
            return true;
    return false;
}
```

`isPossible(n,0)` returns the boolean value corresponding to whether the number `n` is possible to be expressed as sum of unique numbers from the set `allNumbers[]`. But the complexity of this solution is `O(2^32)`. Is it possible to get a better run time for this problem?

Comment: O(2^32) would be constant time. pretty sure you got you notation wrong here.

Comment: @NathanOliver Thank you!

Comment: @litelite it is `2^N` if the size of set is `N`

Comment: @litelite if the number of positive integers is always `32` then the complexity is indeed constant

Comment: So your complexity should be O(2^N) because in the algorithm the size of `allNumber` might change.